# Flutter: implement any authentication in Firebase storage with google authentication fails

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

my app is using this code in flutter to upload images:

```
final StorageReference imageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('postimages');
    final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = imageRef.child('/' + currentUser.id + '/post_$postid.jpg').putFile(_image);
    var upurl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    url = upurl.toString();
    debugPrint('url:$url');
```

which is working fine if i grant full rewrite access by these unrecommended rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

but if i try to implement any security for example with this rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {      
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;

    }
  }
}
```

i end up getting the following exception:
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error -13021, FIRStorageErrorDomain, User does not have permission to access gs://picturegramm.appspot.com/postimages/118190432651181005229/post_b050df01-7b58-4016-8d3c-28c7f3ace630.jpg., null)

The app is using firebase authentication with google as sign-in provider.
Reading the docs it looks like the **auth info is always sent automatically**.
The signing seems to work perfectly, since i am getting the current user with the userid.
**So why do the requests fail?**

Comment: Are you sure the user has signed in with google. If the user is signed out this will not work. They must be signed in.

Comment: Any idea how i verify this before uploading? The login seems to be working since i am getting e.g. email, id and profile pic from it.

Comment: Check if the user exists by `final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;` `user` will be null if the user isn't logged in.

Comment: ty! it is null. now i have to find out why that is the case after a signing has been completed

Comment: Now at least you have narrowed down the problem. I'm guessing you have some error somewhere in your login logic.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the comments from Gabe i found out the code is indeed valid, but my authentication was incomplete, since i was not passing the login to firebase.
for future reference this the complete login code that is needed to make it work:

```
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

  // Obtain the auth details from the request
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  // Create a new credential
  final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
  UserCredential creds = await  FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  debugPrint('creds:$creds');
```